# How to loop through individual cells of array

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Have inherited a macro that I'm not 100% on, and I need to fix it.  Essentially it should check if each of the reference cells are populated, if true - copy to plan cell, if isEmpty, do nothing.  However seems it copies regardless.

[image]

Have tried adding for each loop but doesn't seem to be taking effect.

```
refGap = findRefGap(refCol, LR, valToCopy)
planGap = findPlanGap(refCol, LR)



For i = 23 To LR
    'Checks to see if the cell is actually referencing a product.
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, prodCol).value) = False And Cells(i, prodCol).value <> "Result" Then
'        RefPt is the row where ref demand is found, same with planPt to planned non-promoted volume.
        refPt = i + refGap
        planPt = i + planGap

        Range(Cells(refPt, calCol), Cells(refPt, LC)).copy
        Range(Cells(planPt, calCol), Cells(planPt, LC)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Have you verified that the cells are not empty (no spaces) and that the exact string is "Result" not `Like "Result"`?

Comment: Hi Cyril, yes have checked that the cells are totally empty.   Even used formula in excel frontend to check isblank = true.  Thanks

Comment: Instead of involving the clipboard, you can do `Range(Cells(planPt, calCol), Cells(planPt, LC)).Value = Range(Cells(refPt, calCol), Cells(refPt, LC)).Value`. Note that unless this code is written in some worksheet module's code-behind, it's implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`. Unqualified `Cells` and `Range` calls should be preceded by a `Worksheet` object and a dot, e.g. `Sheet1.Cells(...)`.

Comment: Is `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in that procedure? If so, remove it: if `Cells(i, prodCol).Value` contains a worksheet error, the `<> "Result"` comparison is throwing a *type mismatch* error and `Resume Next` is interfering with the condition and making the whole block unconditional in these occurrences.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks.  the function being called works on the active sheet, but I take your point.  Don't have On Error Resume Next.

Comment: There's not really enough information here to be able to point to something and say "that's the problem."  This really would benefit from providing sample data and expected results.  It would also be very helpful if you posted the full code instead of just the snippet since the snippet appears valid as is.

Comment: @tigeravatar thanks.  The entirety of the code is huge, so can't put it all here.  Seems to me this is the part that goes wrong.    Guess what I need to make happen is instead of copying the array of cells, it should test each individually and then copy if the test is passed

Comment: (1) Are you saying the If evaluates to True on every iteration? (2) What is the value of `LR`? (3) What is the value of `prodCol`?

Comment: It looks like the block of "Overall Result" / "Plan" / "Reference" repeats itself, is that correct?  Is there always only one "Plan" row and one "Reference" row per block?

Comment: @tigeravatar yes it loops over multiple blocks as many times as needed till the sheet is completed.  One of each per block right.  Thanks

Comment: @SJR yes seems to eval to true regardless of data in the reference range.  LR is the last row, so the final block.  prodCol is a cell 4 columns back contains a product description

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rPlan As Range
    Dim rReference As Range
    Dim sHeadersCol As String
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim lCol As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    sHeadersCol = "A"

    Set rPlan = ws.Columns(sHeadersCol).Find("Plan", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sHeadersCol), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rPlan Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rPlan.Address
        Do
            Set rReference = ws.Range(rPlan, rPlan.End(xlDown)).Find("Reference", rPlan, xlValues, xlWhole)
            If Not rReference Is Nothing Then
                For lCol = rPlan.Column + 1 To rPlan.Column + rPlan.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 1
                    If Len(Trim(ws.Cells(rReference.Row, lCol).Value)) > 0 Then ws.Cells(rPlan.Row, lCol).Value = ws.Cells(rReference.Row, lCol).Value
                Next lCol
            End If
            Set rPlan = ws.Columns(sHeadersCol).Find("Plan", rPlan, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop Until rPlan.Address = sFirst
    End If

End Sub
```